# PostgreSQL: Conditional insert default values

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, auto-increment

How do we conditionally insert a row with its default values into a table?

For example, we have a table with one column.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY
);
```

And, we want to do something like below:

```
INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES
WHERE random() >= 0.5;
```

But, we get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
```

Comment: I'm sure you have a reason, but this seems like an odd thing to do. Out of curiosity, what are you hoping to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO foo
SELECT -- here is empty select, without any columns
WHERE random() >= 0.5;
```

[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=80d69d095ab3d346f3b368c8963fae83)

PS: There are several "curious" related things in PostgreSQL. For example, `select;` or even more `create table t();` both are valid statements.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional insert requires a query and, as you can see from the [INSERT documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html), `query` and `DEFAULT VALUES` are in a exclusive group.

When explicitly defining what columns should be populated, you need to specify at least one. So something like this is also invalid:

```
INSERT INTO foo ()
SELECT 1
WHERE random() >= 0.5;
```

The only way I can think of to achieve the same effect is by explicitly defining the "default" value:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id)
SELECT nextval('foo_id_seq'::regclass)
WHERE random() > 0.8;
```

Or by adding another column

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    ignored SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO foo (ignored) 
SELECT 1
WHERE random() >= 0.5;
```

Edit:

Completely missed that you can do empty selects:

```
INSERT INTO foo
SELECT
WHERE random() >= 0.5;
```